# Some device dont's receive push notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM push notification with play services 8.4 and sending via php with high priority.
In my Android 4.3 I receive the message, even if after a few minutes while a J5 Samsung with Android 5.1 can take several hours and sometimes is not even received.
I followed the google implementation guidelines for the gcm.
In diagnosing GCM for the J5 of the message tracking token it is indicated as received by GCM but nothing else.
J5 on other applications (whatsapp) receive notifications even in standby but not mine. Now it is as I seek solutions.
I tried through alarm to wake up the manager app to input this, I tried with all the mechanisms suggested by Google but nothing.
I found the information about it of 'HeartBeat but I understood that only decreases the contact time (from 28 minutes to as many as you want in a mobile connection) of the device to the GCM but the situation would not change.
I do not care if the message comes after one hour, but the important thing is to arrive before my death.
Help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.customer.myapp"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionCode="20"
android:versionName="1.4.4" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"  
/>

<permission android:name="com.customer.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.customer.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" 
android:maxSdkVersion="23"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/main_logo" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 <!-- .GcmBroadcastReceiver, Aggiunto exported -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.customer.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".MyGCMListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver
        android:name=".Boot"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".FBActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_fb"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.customer.myapp.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"           
android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProviderXXXXXXXXX"
        android:exported="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".FacebookBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action   
android:name="com.facebook.platform.AppCallResultBroadcast" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".WebviewAct"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_webview"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.customer.myapp.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ArgomentiActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_argomenti"
        android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.customer.myapp.Main" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Luoghi"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_luoghi" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"     
android:exported="false"></service>
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".BroadcastFormyapp">   
</receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".ServiceAlarm"
        android:enabled="true"
         >  <!-- android:process=":" -->   
    </service>       
    <service
        android:name=".GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
     </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Payload in PHP:

```
    $fields=array(
    "registration_ids"=>$registration_ids,
    "delay_while_idle" => true,
    "priority" => "high",
    "data"=>$message
);
```

Comment: See if that would'nt be your case: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2216

Comment: It would help a lot if you can post code snippets of your payload. I think.

Comment: Marcin the heartbeat for me is not fundamental. The problem is the device J5 not receive message push, the state in console diagnostic CGM remains in Accept.

Comment: Heya, you might wanna check the solution in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409143/some-devices-does-not-receive-gcm-push-eventhough-all-messages-succeed-from-serv). It seems related and might be of help ; )

Comment: speaking from my experiences with the same issue, Some devices (Samsung mostly) tend to disable some Google Play Services features such as GCM when they are not being used to save battery. check to make sure the GcmService is running on the device in `running services`. if it is not then you know the phone is killing it

Comment: If what tyczj is actually causing the issue, try playing around with the payload. See if something happens when `priority="normal"`. If it doesn't check out that thread by noogui.