# Download image in GcmListenerService and post notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, picasso, gcmlistenerservice

I am using a GcmReceiver with a listener that extends GcmListenerService.
In my onMessageReceived method, I want to download a remote image (using Picasso lib) and once the image has been downloaded, post a notification to the user.

**Code:**

```
public class MainGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String urlImage = data.getString("image_url");
        final Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context) ...... // build a notification with the downloaded image as a logo
                  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                  mNotificationManager.notify(notificationType.getValue(), mBuilder.build());
            }
        };
        Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(context).load(urlImage)
                        .into(target);
            }
        });
```

This code works well most of the time, but sometimes the notification is not posted. I assume this is due to the fact that the GCM message thread gets killed before the download image task is finished. What would be a correct way to implement such a process in a GcmListenerService (downloading an image in onMessageReceived and then posting the notification once its finished)?

Comment: Interesting. How often does the Notification not shown (process killed as per your post) ?

Comment: I see around 5% of users experiencing  it per push notification. I assume this is the root cause (since I see they report receiving the gcm, but the local notification is not posted)

Comment: It's hard to provide a definite answer.. The way Picasso works, it may also depend on the internet connection of the receiving device, there still always a chance of the process being killed. What I would do in your situation though is to have a `default image` to be shown if a specific amount of time has elapsed, just to ensure that a notification is shown.

Comment: may be CPU goes to sleep. Hope this linkt can help you [Keep the CPU On](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#cpu)

Comment: @McAwesomville . thanks for the info. Is there anyway to know how long the gcm thread onMessageReceived is allowed run?

Comment: No problem. Gonna post it as an answer for the community to see. Might actually help others. With regards to the gcm thread, I'm not sure. It may vary even per device. I think I've read somewhere that Samsung devices often kill Google Play Services process much quicker.

Comment: This is where I've read about the Samsung thing, see one of the [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37044734/4625829).

Comment: @Ohad can u tell how u resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to provide a definite and complete answer. The way Picasso works, it may also depend on the internet connection of the receiving device, there still always a chance of the process being killed.

What I would do in your situation though is to have a default image in the client app to be used for the `Notification`, if within a specific amount of time has already elapsed and the image still isn't downloaded completely, just to ensure that a `Notification` is shown.